# Problems with complex UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to implement a custom complex `UITableViewCell`. My data source is relatively simple, but I could have some multiple elements.

```
class Element: NSObject {
    var id: String
    var titles: [String]
    var value: String

    init(id: String, titles: [String], value: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.titles = titles
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

I have an array of elements `[Element]` and, as you can see, for each element `titles` could have multiple string values. I must use the following layouts:

[image: single_cell]

[image: double_cell]

[image: multiple_cell]

My first approach was to implement a dynamic UITableViewCell, trying to add content inside `self.contentView` at runtime. Everything is working, but it's not so fine and as you can see, reusability is not handled in the right way. Lag is terrible.

```
import UIKit

class ElementTableCell: UITableViewCell {

    var titles: [String]!
    var value: String!
    var width: CGFloat!
    var titleViewWidth: CGFloat!
    var cellHeight: Int!

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:)")
    }

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        self.selectionStyle = .none
    }

    func drawLayout() {
        titleViewWidth = (width * 2)/3
        cellHeight = 46 * titles.count

        for i in 0 ..< titles.count {
            let view = initTitleView(title: titles[i], width: titleViewWidth, yPosition: CGFloat(cellHeight * i))
            self.contentView.addSubview(view)
        }

        self.contentView.addSubview(initButton())
    }

    func initTitleView(title: String, width: CGFloat, yPosition: CGFloat) -> UIView {
        let titleView: UILabel = UILabel(frame:CGRect(x:0, y:Int(yPosition), width: Int(width), height: 45))
        titleView.text = title
        return titleView
    }

    func initButton(value: String) -> UIButton {
        let button = UIButton(frame:CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 70, height:34))
        button.setTitle(value, for: .normal)
        button.center.x = titleViewWidth + ((width * 1)/3)/2
        button.center.y = CGFloat(cellHeight/2)
        return priceButton
    }
}
```

And the UITableView delegate method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = ElementTableCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "ElementTableCell")

    cell.width = self.view.frame.size.width
    cell.titles = elements[indexPath.row].titles
    cel.value = elements[indexPath.row].value
    cell.drawLayout()

    return cell
}
```

Now I'm thinking about a total different approach, such as using a UITableView Section for each element in `elements` array and a UITableViewCell for each title in titles. It could work, but I'm concerned about the right button.
Do you have any suggestion or other approach to share?

Comment: First, with your initial approach... because cells are reused, you are adding labels and buttons *every time* a cell is displayed. That means if you scroll up and down, each cell is getting multiple layers of labels and buttons. Second... is there a max number of Titles? or (virtually) unlimited?

Comment: Thank you for your answer DonMag. That's the reason why I wrote that reusability is not handled. Anyway sadly titles are "virtually" unlimited.

Comment: Even with lots of titles, if you handle reuse properly it shouldn't be a slow process. I would put the labels (and horizontal lines) into a `UIStackView` and let constraints handle the rest.

Comment: With first try I can't handle reuse in a correct way. With second approach I should, but it's impossible to center button inside cell, because a full cell will be a section.

Comment: Is this about what you have in mind?  https://imgur.com/a/8yEAd

Comment: @DonMag exactly. That's what I've got in my mind

Comment: @JJack_  have you tried profiling your app with instruments to pinpoint your bottlenecks?

Comment: Yep, no memory leak. Only slow framerate and high memory allocation on scrolling up and down. I tried with 2.000 table view cell.

Answer (score 1):

I solved changing application UI logic in order to overcome the problem. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code you can play with. It *should* work just be creating a new `UITableView` in a Storyboard and assigning it to `BoxedTableViewController` in this file...

```
//
//  BoxedTableViewController.swift
//

import UIKit

class BoxedCell: UITableViewCell {

    var theStackView: UIStackView!
    var containingView: UIView!
    var theButton: UIButton!

    var brdColor = UIColor(white: 0.7, alpha: 1.0)

    // "spacer" view is just a 1-pt tall UIView used as a horizontal-line between labels
    //      when there is more than one title label
    func getSpacer() -> UIView {

        let newView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 1))
        newView.backgroundColor = brdColor

        newView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        newView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1.0).isActive = true

        return newView

    }

    // "label view" is a UIView containing on UILabel
    //      embedding the label in a view allows for convenient borders and insets
    func getLabelView(text: String, position: Int) -> UIView {

        let v = UIView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        let newLabel = UILabel()
        newLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15.0)
        newLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.8, alpha: 1.0)
        newLabel.textColor = .black

        newLabel.layer.borderWidth = 1
        newLabel.layer.borderColor = brdColor.cgColor

        newLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        newLabel.text = text

        newLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        v.addSubview(newLabel)

        newLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0).isActive = true
        newLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0).isActive = true

        var iTop: CGFloat = 0.0
        var iBot: CGFloat = 0.0

        // the passed "position" tells me whether this label is:
        //      a Single Title only
        //      the first Title of more than one
        //      the last Title of more than one
        //      or a Title with a Title above and below
        // so we can set up proper top/bottom padding

        switch position {
        case 0:
            iTop = 16.0
            iBot = 16.0
            break

        case 1:
            iTop = 12.0
            iBot = 8.0
            break

        case -1:
            iTop = 8.0
            iBot = 12.0
            break

        default:
            iTop = 8.0
            iBot = 8.0
            break
        }

        newLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v.topAnchor, constant: iTop).isActive = true
        newLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v.bottomAnchor, constant: -iBot).isActive = true

        return v

    }

    func setupThisCell(rowNumber: Int) -> Void {

        // if containingView is nil, it hasn't been created yet
        //      so, create it + Stack view + Button
        // else
        //      don't create new ones
        // This way, we don't keep adding more and more views to the cell on reuse

        if containingView == nil {

            containingView = UIView()
            containingView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

            contentView.addSubview(containingView)

            containingView.layer.borderWidth = 1
            containingView.layer.borderColor = brdColor.cgColor
            containingView.backgroundColor = .white

            containingView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0).isActive = true
            containingView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0).isActive = true

            containingView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 6.0).isActive = true
            containingView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -6.0).isActive = true

            theStackView = UIStackView()
            theStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

            containingView.addSubview(theStackView)

            theStackView.axis = .vertical
            theStackView.spacing = 4.0
            theStackView.alignment = .fill
            theStackView.distribution = .fill

            theButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
            theButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

            containingView.addSubview(theButton)

            theButton.backgroundColor = .blue
            theButton.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
            theButton.setTitle("The Button", for: .normal)

            theButton.setContentHuggingPriority(1000, for: .horizontal)

            theButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containingView.centerYAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
            theButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containingView.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0).isActive = true

            theStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containingView.topAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
            theStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containingView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
            theStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containingView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true

            theStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theButton.leadingAnchor, constant: -8.0).isActive = true

        }

        // remove all previously added Title labels and spacer views

        for v in theStackView.arrangedSubviews {
            v.removeFromSuperview()
        }

        // setup 1 to 5 Titles
        let n = rowNumber % 5 + 1

        // create new Title Label views and, if needed, spacer views
        //      and add them to the Stack view

        if n == 1 {

            let aLabel = getLabelView(text: "Only one title for row: \(rowNumber)", position: 0)
            theStackView.addArrangedSubview(aLabel)

        } else {

            for i in 1..<n {

                let aLabel = getLabelView(text: "Title number \(i)\n for row: \(rowNumber)", position: i)
                theStackView.addArrangedSubview(aLabel)
                let aSpacer = getSpacer()
                theStackView.addArrangedSubview(aSpacer)

            }

            let aLabel = getLabelView(text: "Title number \(n)\n for row: \(rowNumber)", position: -1)
            theStackView.addArrangedSubview(aLabel)

        }

    }

}

class BoxedTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    let cellID = "boxedCell"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.register(BoxedCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellID)

        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

        self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)

    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1250
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath) as! BoxedCell

        // Configure the cell...

        cell.setupThisCell(rowNumber: indexPath.row)

        return cell

    }

}
```

I'll check back if you run into any problems with it (gotta run, and haven't fully tested it yet -- and ran out of time to comment it - ugh).

Comment: I really want to thank you for your code! I'm starting to play with it. Anyway I don't understand why it should be different from first solution I shared in order to handle reuse. For each indexPath row it drops new label programatically, so it should be memory consuming. Right? I tried on real device and It's very laggy with 1500 results :(

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `UIStackView`s, while convenient, lack in performance themselves.

Comment: @Losiowaty I also pointed out that autolayout in tableview cell could degrade performances.

Comment: @JJack_ - I made a few edits and added some comments. The code checks for `containingView == nil` and only creates new `containingView`, `Stack View` and `Button` if they have not yet been created (avoids duplicates). Then it removes any existing "Title Labels" and spacer lines before adding in the new ones. This *could* be a bit more efficient by reusing the Title labels, but if the requirement is "potentially 200 title labels in a single row" we're kinda stuck. I can't run this on a device until tomorrow, but I'd be interested in your definition of "very laggy"...

Answer (score 0):

You can also use tableview as tableviecell and adjust cell accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

u need to layout cell in func layoutsubviews after set data to label and imageview;

Answer (score 0):

Yes, split `ElementTableCell` to section with header and cells is much better approach. In this case you have no need to create constraints or dealing with complex manual layout. This would make your code simple and make scrolling smooth. 
The button you use can be easily moved to the reusable header view

Is you still want to keep it in one complete cell, where is a way to draw manually the dynamic elements, such as titles and separators lines. Manually drawing is faster as usual. Or remove all views from cell.contentView each time you adding new.  But this way is much more complicated.

Greate article about how to make UITableView appearence swmoth:
[Perfect smooth scrolling in UITableViews](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/perfect-smooth-scrolling-in-uitableviews-fd609d5275a5)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just read the article you shared, it's awesome. I don't understand what you mean with moving button to the header. Unfortunately I must you the layout I shared. In my case this button it's the problem.

Comment: You can set your custom view inherited from UITableViewHeaderFooterView which would contain this button. In following method:  func headerView(forSection section: Int) -> UITableViewHeaderFooterView

Comment: but it won't be on the right center of the section, am I right?

Comment: Oh, yes. I didn't get you need button to be exactly on the right of the titles. Then drawing all omitting button may be a good solution. Clearing context and drawing each time is is updated

Comment: I figured out that one possible solution could be use UICollectionView. Each section could be a row and title and button could be two different UICollectionView cell per row. Using this approach I think that one possible side effect could be an extremely memory consumption. Eg. (600 res -> 1200 cell)